# .scroll() is only running once

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to create a small snippet for a sticky sidebar with jQuery. For some reason, the function inside of `.scroll()` is only running once instead of running at every scroll event. What could I be doing wrong?

```
var sticky = $('#sticky');
var staticSticky = $(sticky).offset().top;

$(window).scroll(moveEl(sticky, staticSticky));

function moveEl(element, staticElToTop){
    if( $(window).scrollTop() >= staticElToTop ){
        $(element).css('top', $(window).scrollTop() + 'px');
    }
}
```

See here for the entire attempt: http://codepen.io/ExcellentSP/pen/GqZwVG

The code above is not fully functional. I'm just trying to get the scroll event to work properly before I continue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap content of your your `moveEl` method into the function (to be returned for `$(window).scroll()`) like this:

```
var sticky = $('#sticky');
var staticSticky = $(sticky).offset().top;

$(window).scroll(moveEl(sticky, staticSticky));

function moveEl(element, staticElToTop) {
  return function() {
    if( $(window).scrollTop() >= staticElToTop ){
        $(element).css('top', $(window).scrollTop() + 'px');
    }
  }
}
```

**Explanation:**
The key difference is that you call a function and it returns `undefined` by default, so it equals to `$(window).scroll(undefined)`. Since you actually called it, you see it's fired only once which is obvious.

As soon as you return a function within `moveEl` method, `.scroll()` gets a handler, so it becomes `$(window).scroll(handler)`. So it will work now as expected.

Comment: Is there some reference material that explains the difference? I'm still developing my understanding of the library. Please include in your answer. The documentation says this for the handler, "A function to execute each time the event is triggered."

Answer (score 0):

In doing that $(window).scroll(moveEl(sticky, staticSticky));, you ask to javascript to execute the function. You don't pass its reference.

```
 $(window).scroll(function(){ 
   moveEl(sticky, staticSticky);
 });
```

Comment: The solution of #Oleg Meleshko is more elegant. But the why is the same.